# Change background accordingly in jQuery tab menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background-image

I am working on a website with a tab menu which lets you switch between different tabs with information about the characters (of a series). I've followed a simple tutorial with jQuery, and the menu works like it should, but I want to change the background of the menu accordingly to the currently selected character. This is the basic code:

Javascript:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="etc/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
var tabs = $('#menuv_characters_titles li');
var contents = $('#menuv_characters_contents li');

tabs.bind('click',function(){
  contents.hide();
  tabs.removeClass('current_title');
  $(contents[$(this).index()]).show(); //show tab content that matches tab title index
  $(this).addClass('current_title');
});
});
</script>
</head>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menuv_characters">
    <ul id="menuv_characters_titles">
        <li class="current_title">
            Character 1
        </li>
        <li>
            Character 2
        </li>
        <li>
            Character 3
        </li>
        <li>
            Character 4
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="menuv_characters_contents">
        <li>Text 1</li>
        <li>Text 2</li>
        <li>Text 3</li>
        <li>Text 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My Question is: How do I get the name or index (Identifier ↓) of the currently selected tab, so that I can change the background-image accordingly?

```
$('#menuv_characters_titles').css('background-image', 'url(img/'+Identifier+'.png)');
```

Comment: can you give an example of what your image names are?

Comment: Hm, maybe 'frame_1', 'frame_2', etc? But I can also rename them if this makes it easier :)

Comment: `var identifier = $(this).??????;`, you tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the index of the currently selected tab you just have to call `$(this).index();`

So you could do something like this:

```
var Identifier = $(this).index();

$('#menuv_characters_titles').css('background-image', 'url(img/frame_'+Identifier+'.png)');
```

Also `.bind()` is deprecated use `.on()` instead for your click event or simply call:

```
tabs.click(function(){
```

You could also add your image name as a data attribute to your `li` if you wanted to like so:

```
<li data-image="frame_1">text</li>
```

and then pull that on your click event like so:

```
var Identifier = $(this).data("image");

$('#menuv_characters_titles').css('background-image', 'url(img/'+Identifier+'.png)');
```

Comment: I've changed .bind(). And you solution works great too. Thanks :D

Comment: you got it. glad to help